# Querying from multiple application insight across tenants

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-analytics

We are migrating one application from one resource group to another resource group which is on a different tenant. We are using application insight custom event to log custom data and using that data in a power bi Report using app insight analytics queries. We do not want to loose the last 90 days data in this migration since those data are critical to customer.

I am aware that we can join multiple application insight data using "union". It works fine when the application insights are in same tenant. But it does not work when app insights are in different tenant.

Question: Is there a way where I can migrate the data of old application insight to new application insight or can perform some similar action like union operation to get the report from both resources(old and new application insight).

Answer (score 1):

Querying across tenants is not supported (in UX). One way to do it is to query data and visualize it yourself (for instance, Azure Notebook or Jupyter Notebook).